# MySQL how to adress columns that are generated in a pivot table to sum their values

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic-sql

**SOLVED**

> I'am so sorry guys, it was so easy, but workday smashed my brain.
>
> I just had to made the sum on the basis of id to get what i need, like
>   this:
>
> ```
> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT tt.Id, SUM(tt.Values) AS TOTAL, ' @sql, ' FROM db.Table tt GROUP BY tt.Id');
> ```
>
> Thank you for help!

Your help is really appreciated :)

I have a generated table of the following a look:

```
id      | key1    |   key2   | ... | keyN 

id_val1 | k1_val1 | k2_val1  | ... | kN_val1

...     | ...     |  ...     | ... | ...
id_valM | k1_valM |  k2_valM | ... | kN_valM
```

it is generated with the code:

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(tt.Keys = ''',
      tt.Keys,
      ''', tt.Values, NULL)) AS ',
      tt.Keys
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM db.Table tt;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT tt.Id, ', @sql, ' FROM db.Table tt GROUP BY tt.Id WITH ROLLUP');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

What I have to do is to add Total column, like this:

```
id      | key1    |   key2   | ... | keyN    | Total

id_val1 | k1_val1 | k2_val1  | ... | kN_val1 | sum(k1_val1, k2_val1,...,kN_val1)

...     | ...     |  ...     | ... | ...     | ...
id_valM | k1_valM |  k2_valM | ... | kN_valM | sum(k1_valM, k2_valM,...,kN_valM)
```

"WITH ROLLUP" didn't work though, it only added another row with max values in columns, while I need sums in rows.

The problem is the fact that number of columns and their names may differ through time. And using their names properly is the problem itself :).

For example i got the names of columns, but how to use them, as they don't belong to any table? I can convert dynamically built sql to the following look. But can you tell me how the @xxx should look:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT tt.Id, SUM(', @xxx,') AS TOTAL, ' @sql, ' FROM db.Table tt GROUP BY tt.Id WITH ROLLUP');
```

Thanks in advance,
Michael.

Comment: k1_val1 + k2_val1 + ... + kN_val1

Comment: The problem is the fact that number of columns and their names may differ through time. And getting their names is the problem itself :)

Comment: Afaik there's no way around it, there's no simple function: sum up all columns without naming them individually :-)

Comment: Have just made the question more exact

Comment: Since you use `GROUP_CONCAT` you are getting a string (varchar) as the result.  You need to write a function that splits it, then in a loop converts each part to numeric and sums them up.

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting this correctly, I think this is what you want to do.  You aren't actually doing a sum, correct?  You are adding all of the field values for each row.  The second GROUP_CONCAT here should create the list of fields with plus signs (+) in between them.  Give it a shot.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @sql2 = NULL;

SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
                        CONCAT(
                                  'MAX(IF(tt.Keys = ''',
                                  tt.Keys,
                                  ''', tt.Values, NULL)) AS ',
                                  tt.Keys
                              )
                    ) INTO @sql,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
                        CONCAT(
                                  'MAX(IF(tt.Keys = ''',
                                  tt.Keys,
                                  ''', tt.Values, NULL))'
                              )
                     SEPARATOR '+'
                    ) INTO @sql2
FROM db.Table tt;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT tt.Id, ', @sql, ', ', @sql2,' AS Total FROM db.Table tt GROUP BY tt.Id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but it doesn't work, actually. Even if I use following statement:

Comment: Thank you for help, but it doesn't work, actually. Even if I use following statement:   `SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT tt.Id, SUM(key1,key2) AS TOTAL, ', @sql,' FROM db.Table tt GROUP BY tt.Id');` - it doesn't work.

Comment: Is it possible for you to show the SQL that is being created?  Or a SQL fiddle perhaps?

Comment: What I was attempting to do was to create an expression like this: `k1_val1 + k2_val1 + ... + kN_val1 AS Total`.

Comment: `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' key2) AS TOTAL, MAX(IF(tt.Keys = 'key1', tt.Values, NULL)) AS key1' at line 1` - this is an error i got if i input key names into SUM() directly as shown above.

Comment: Ough, I am sorry, it was an error from unsuccessfully modified code. It just tells that there are no such columns: `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'key1' in 'field list'`

Comment: I am not using the field names.  I am taking the results from your GROUP_CONCAT and adding them.  Ex: Your GROUP_CONAT returns something like this: `100 as key1, 300 as key2, 200 as key3`.  I am attempting to create this: `100 + 300 + 200 as Total`.